# how to open selenium webdriver one time and use it

Tags: c#

i have a simple website (https://www.orbismodding.com/) and i want to automate it.
i used selenium firefox webdriver to do this , and created a button click to send a text into a input filed and click on search button and get the results to a textbox
my code :

```
        private void mtboxCUSA_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cusa = mtboxCUSA.Text;
            FirefoxOptions firefoxBinary = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxBinary.AddArgument("-headless");
            firefoxBinary.AddArgument("--width=300");
            firefoxBinary.AddArgument("--height=300");
            firefoxBinary.SetPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
            firefoxBinary.SetPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
            var ffds = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            ffds.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffds, firefoxBinary);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.orbismodding.com/");
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#titleID")));
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#titleID")).SendKeys(cusa);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchBtn")).Click();
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/h3")));
            string gname = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/h3")).Text;
            btboxCusaResult.Text = gname;

        }
```

the problem is every time i click on the button its take time to open a fresh webdriver window to do the automation ! how can i use the existing webdriver that i used before ?
and is there any other way else selenium ? (like HttpRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep it simple and add a class variable for **driver** and for the **wait** objects.

You would end up with something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;
private void mtboxCUSA_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cusa = mtboxCUSA.Text;
    if(driver == null)
    {
        FirefoxOptions firefoxBinary = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxBinary.AddArgument("-headless");
        firefoxBinary.AddArgument("--width=300");
        firefoxBinary.AddArgument("--height=300");
        firefoxBinary.SetPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
        firefoxBinary.SetPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
        var ffds = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        ffds.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffds, firefoxBinary); 
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.orbismodding.com/");
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#titleID")));
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#titleID")).SendKeys(cusa);
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchBtn")).Click();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/h3")));
    string gname = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/h3")).Text;
    btboxCusaResult.Text = gname;
}
```

If you want to test the data coming to your website, and assuming you have a REST Api on the back-end of your website, you could do integration tests against your APIs.
In this case, you would be using using an **HttpClient** to do your tests.

Comment: Thank you Julien ! add a class variable for driver and for the wait objects works perfect , that is what i need.